# Normals per face in OpenTK/GL

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I was wondering how to set a normal array for faces instead for vertices with `NormalPointer`. I use `DrawElements` for drawing quads but edge vertices are always shared with multiple quads so the definition of normals per vertex is not helpful. When I duplicate vertices and use no `ElementArrayBuffer` I can solve this by using `DrawArrays`. However, the duplication of the vertices and using `DrawArrays` results in inaccaptable artefacts between the quads. Is there any possibility to use a list of face normals together with `ElementArrayBuffer`? Can this only be done with shaders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "However, the duplication of the vertices and using DrawArrays results in inaccaptable artefacts between the quads" - What happens exactly? Per-face data doesn't exist in OpenGL, the only solution is to duplicate vertices.

Comment: In my case I use many faces for one plane. Depending on the view edges become visible, see https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuBwnapMrqaghuoU0RC2FuLIEDIlRw

Comment: (you see faces from the inside)